# how i can send more than 2 arguments on telnet session in python?

Tags: python, networking, telnet

I have two lists that have user name and password. I want to check which one is correct by iterating through two zipped lists but it isn't working.
Below is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mohamed\Downloads\second_PassWD_Test.py", line 27, in <module>
mme=tn.write(j,i)
TypeError: write() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

---

Below is the code throwing the exception.

```
import telnetlib
import re
HOST = "192.168.1.1"
USER =  ["admin\n","admin\n","admin"]
PASS = ["cpe#","1234"," "]

try:
  tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
except:
print "Oops! there is a connection error"
frist_log = tn.read_until(":")
 if "log" in frist_log:
while 1:
    for i,j in zip(USER,PASS):
         tn.write(j,i)
    break
```

Comment: change the order on tn.write(i,j) and check the docu, there are great examples for a clean setup https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html

Comment: thanks Ari, but i can't find any thing related to my quotation, i need to send item from list every time by the For loop

Comment: `telnet.Write(buffer)` only takes the buffer argument what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: One way to solve your issue is to create a telnetlib expect script where every time you use `write` you wait for a session using the `expect` api call

Answer (score 1):

`Telnet.write(buffer)` only takes two arguments first is the telnet object and the other is a buffer to send to your session, hence your solution will throw an exception. One way to solve the problem is like a except script using  the `expect` api and use a list of expected output as shown in example below

```
USER =  ["admin\n","admin\n","admin"]
PASS = ["cpe#","1234"," "]
prompt = "#"    ## or your system prompt 
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
first_log = tn.read_until(":")
for user,password in zip(USER,PASS):
    try:
        tn.write(user)
        tn.expect([":"],timeout = 3) # 3 second timeout for password prompt
        tn.write(password+"\n")
        index,obj,string = tn.expect([":",prompt],timeout = 3)
        found = string.find(prompt)
        if found >= 0:
            break # found the username password match break 
        ###else continue for next user/password match    
    except:
        print "exception",sys.exc_info()[0]
```

Comment: thtanks my friend cmidi ,, but isn't work when i tested it i found that code not send a user name "admin" so i tried to change USER list to be ((( USER = "admin" ))) and  sent it otherwise i can telnet this device by the same users and passWD Via telnet applaction.... could you check with me again ..

Comment: HOST = "192.168.1.1"
    USER =  "admin"
    PASS = ["cpe#","1234","c "]
    prompt = ">>"    ## or your system prompt 
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
    first_log = tn.read_until(":")
    for user,password in zip(USER,PASS):
        try:
            me=tn.write(user)
            print me
            tn.expect([":"],timeout = 3) # 3 second timeout for password prompt
           tn.write(password)
            index,obj,string = tn.expect([":",prompt],timeout = 3)
            found = string.find(prompt)
            if found > = 0:

Comment: @M.hosseny Where is it failing adding prints or enabling debug can help. the code I added was missing a `"\n"` which I have added. to enable debug `Telnet.set_debuglevel(4)`. Also mind that `zip(USER,PASS)` if the sizes are different will zip the result to lower size list which could cause a problem, make sure that USER and PASS are same size if you are using zip